# Does packing BooleanTensor's to ByteTensor's affect training of LSTM (or other ML models)?

Tags: memory, pytorch, tensor

I am working on an LSTM to generate music. My input data will be a `BooleanTensor` of size `88xLx3`, `88` being the amount of available notes, `L` being the length of each "piece" which will be in the order of 1k - 10k (TBD), and `3` being the parts for "lead melody", "accompaniment", and "bass". A value of `0` would symbolize that that specific note is not being played by that part (instrument) at that time, and a `1` would symbolize that it is.

The problem is that each entry of a `BooleanTensor` takes 1 byte of space in memory instead of 1 bit, which wastes a lot of valuable GPU memory.

As a solution I thought of packing each `BooleanTensor` to a `ByteTensor` (uint8) of size `11xLx3` or `88x(L/8)x3`.

My question is: Would packing the data as such have an effect on the learning and generation of the LSTM or would the `ByteTensor`-based data and model be equivalent to their `BooleanTensor`-based counterparts in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't really care about the fact that the input is taking X instead of Y number of bits, at least when it comes to GPU memory. Most of it is occupied by the network's weights and intermediate outputs, which will likely be `float32` anyway (maybe [float16](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html)). There is active research on training with lower precision (even [binary training](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/file/3e15cc11f979ed25912dff5b0669f2cd-Paper.pdf)), but based on your question, it seems completely unnecessary. Lastly, you can always try [Quantization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html) to your production models, if you really need it.

With regards to the packing: it can have an impact, especially if you do it naively. The grouping you're suggesting doesn't seem to be a natural one, therefore it may be harder to learn patterns from the grouped data than otherwise. There'll always be workarounds, but then this answer become an opinion because it is almost impossible to antecipate what could work; an opinion-based questions/answer are off-topic around here :)

Comment: You are right, for some reason I thought the model was also going to become much more memory efficient, which is definitely not the case. I'll still look into Quantization out of curiosity though. Appreciate the answer as well :)